# Birtviewer Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, birt

I have created the following javascript function to hide or show charts and then calling it from a text item.

```
function showhidetab(showflag,bookmark, heightval, tab)
{
    if (tab == 'overview')
    {
            document.getElementById('overgrid').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('overgrid').style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById('overgrid').style.height= '6in';


    }

    else
    {
            document.getElementById('overgrid').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('overgrid').style.display = "none"
            document.getElementById('overgrid').style.height='0px';


    }

}
```

This function is working when I run it as html or in preview. However, When I deploy the report on birtviewer view it on IE/safari etc, I get the following error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null
>   reference

Can someone please tell me why is the report behaving differently when run through browsers and on Birtviewer/apache

Regards

Syed

Comment: You should make use of IE development tools to inspect if an element "overgrid" is present. Try to run the function manually from the developer console of IE. There are many possible causes, for example IDs of birt elements might be prefixed with a namespace depending on WebViewer setup.

Comment: I also suspect that the name might be prefixed..how can I check what is the gridname being prefeixed with? Its bookmark by the way.is the book mark also prefixed? Can I check this and change the prefix in birtviewer?