# BIRT: Setting Birt viewer paratmer and tag attributes from javascript

Tags: birt

I want to go to a specific page through a button/text item click event. I have put a text item and written an html script make it a button. I want to go to a specific page by setting the __page parameter or calling a bookmark to load.

Can someone please tell me how can I do it through javascript in the html body of a text item

Thanks
Syed

Comment: Have you overcome the issues of your other BIRT questions that you posted recently, that [don't have answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593812)?

Comment: Some of them got answered which I have marked as resolved/correct. I still haven't found solutions for others but am working and asking people on other forums too. If I overcome them, I will asnwer my own questions here or some gentlemen might help me when they get sometime to look at it

Comment: Ah, good to see that the ladies here get some time off, then.